# libatlas package

Tags: 14.04, apt

I am new to Ubuntu. An installation of a machine learning package requires me to install the `libatlas` package with the following bash line (`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git libcurl4-openssl-dev libatlas-`)

However - I get an error message saying that Ubuntu is unable to locate the `libatlas` package. Where might one find this package? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `libatlas-base-dev`

All atlas packages in Ubuntu:

- `libatlas-base-dev`: Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic static
- `libatlas-dev`: Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, C header files
- `libatlas-doc`: Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, documentation
- `libatlas-test`: Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, test programs
- `libatlas3-base`: Automatically Tuned Linear Algebra Software, generic shared
- `libatlas3gf-base`: Transitional package to libatlas3-base